# how to align item bullet to the top of the table in the item

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment

Consider the following example:

```
\section{abc}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      \begin{tabu}[t]{c|c}
        \hline
        $p$ & $p \oplus p$ \\
        \hline
        T & F \\
        F & F \\
        \hline
      \end{tabu}
  \end{enumerate}
```

The bullet a) is above the top line of the table, e.g. the following picture
[image]

How to make the bullet align to the first row of the table, e.g. like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post complete documents so that it makes it easier to test an answer, but:

Replace the first `\hline` by `\firsthline`